# Merging and snapping Tiger line files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, tiger, streets

I have several adjacent (county level) TIGER road files.    I want to merge them and create one contiguous file of snapped roads for the purpose of doing network analysis.   Merging them is easy but how do I get the ends of the roads to snap together properly?

Comment: What software suite do you want to use?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS.   I tried doing a merge and setting the XY tolerance to 1 meter in the environmental variables, to no avail.

Comment: What license do you have for Arc?  [Topology](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000sp000000.htm) would be my route.  I have time for an example, but not a license on this workstation :(

Answer (score 1):

The [Snap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000007000000.htm) tool can be used so that only the starting and ending vertices will be snapped together.

*Be careful though*, as this tool does not have an output; it modifies the input feature class. You should make a copy of your input before running.

Also, this tool doesn't perform "intelligent" snapping. The help mentions:

> the feature with the lower Object or Feature ID will usually be snapped to the feature with the higher Object ID

This means that sometimes, snap won't behave as you would expect. If you have 2 segments that are coincident at the endpoints and a 3rd that is not, the 3rd likely will not be snapped to the other 2 if it has a higher OID than the first three. You might need to experiment with running Snap a few times or moving some intersections manually. See picture below.

[image]