# Snapping line segments together to remove gaps between them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, snapping

I have a series of line segments that were created based on the location of an existing line.  There are small gaps of around 0.1 feet between the different line segments.  I need to somehow snap the 2 ends of the line segments together to remove these small gaps.  Manually snapping them together is not a option as there are literally 100s of these gaps in my dataset.  If arcgis has a tool that will do this that is great but I'm willing to try python or VB whatever will get the job done.  I have included a screencap that illustrates my problem.  The green line is the original and the black segments are what I'm trying to stretch.  I tried geometric networking but it is moving the whole line segment around.  I just need to stretch the line.[image: Line Snapping]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging and snapping Tiger line files](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67339/merging-and-snapping-tiger-line-files)

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a topology and this will fix them with the tolerance setting if you have the correct license (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/topology_in_arcgis.htm).

2) ET Geowizards provides a nifty little clean polyline tool that works.

3) Maybe you can just do feature class to feature class if they are all tiny and just set the environment tolerance to 1m or similar.